# Avoid Incomplete row while getting Items from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I am getting the rows of datagrid as:

```
List<MedicalRecord> updatedList = dataGrid.Items.Cast<MedicalRecord>().ToList();
```

But its throwing exception due to the last incomplete row. How can I cast datagrid rows without getting the last incomplete row. *(I don't want to get into the unnecessary complexities of events and IsModified etc.)* Can it be done in the same line?

Comment: What you mean by **incomplete row?**

Comment: datagrid is already getting data on load event in the form of List<MedicalRecord>, whenever I try to modify any record, it appends one empty row at the end to add new entry, this is what I mean by incomplete row here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
dataGrid.Items.OfType<MedicalRecord>()
```

`Cast` tries to cast each item to the specified type, while `OfType` *filters* the items having the required type.